# Can't return multiple values from this Flask view

Tags: python, flask

The following view will return the `smead` but will not return the second string.  When I try to return variable `john`, I get a 500 error.  How do I fix my view to return the right thing?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template("main.html")

@app.route('/test/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def test():
    import re
    text = "testereread"
    john = re.findall(r'test(.*)$', text)
    smead = "testererere"
    return smead
    return "i swear it no workiez"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Basically you can't have more than 1 return statements, Because the function of the return is to exit the function. so this behaviour happens. Try sending the variables in one return statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you can only return once from a function, so as soon as you `return smead` the function ends and doesn't return the next string.

The second issue is that `re.findall` returns a list.  Flask doesn't know what to do with a list returned from a view, so it throws an error.  You can only return a string or `Response` from a view.

What you probably want to do is render a template that does something with those values.

```
return render_template('test', smead=smead, other='it works', john=john)
```

```html
<p>{{ smead }}: {{ other }}</p>
<ul>{% for item in john %}
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because on the first `return` statement *i.e.* `return smead`, the function exits without checking for the next `return` statement or any other code below.

Try this:

```
return smead + " i swear it no workiez"
```